# Having trouble accessing my API hosted in Cloudflare but not Python Dev Shell

Tags: python, ajax, django, api, cloudflare

So I have a website, lets call it microphone.com. This website has a few apis in it under microphone.com/api1, microphone.com/api2. I'm using ajax to send a request to the APIs with Authorization: JWT  as the header. I've set my settings to accept JWT tokens as authentication for API. Everything works well for when I test it with a virtual python server through my aws (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000)

But when I host the actual site live through Cloudflare's DNS, I get a 401 not authorized whenever I try to access the API. (I can login using session based [meaning going to the APIview and then logging in with the credentials to access API] fine, but when I try to access it remotely through either an ajax request (through microphone.com) or use 'curl -H "Authorization: JWT < token >" microphone.com/api' from my local computer's terminal, I get a 401 authentication credentials were not provided'. Is this because of Cloudflare's security or something? How do I bypass this? I notice there's a cfuid cookie when I enter the live site.

this is my ajax request setup

```
            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(request)
                {
                    request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", " JWT "+jwtToken);
                },
                url: "/api1/",
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'GET',
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It wasn't cloudflare. Apparently when you're deploying to apache using mod_wsgi, the authorization header is not passed through to a WSGI application by default. So I had to add 'WSGIPassAuthorization On' to my httpd.conf file.